# Using sample_weight in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is it possible to perform a `GridSearchCV` (to get the best SVM's C) and yet specify the `sample_weight` with scikit-learn?

Here's my code and the error I'm confronted to:

```py
gs = GridSearchCV(
    svm.SVC(C=1),
    [{
        'kernel': ['linear'],
        'C': [.1, 1, 10],
        'probability': [True],
        'sample_weight': sw_train,
    }]
)

gs.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

> >> ValueError: Invalid parameter sample_weight for estimator SVC

---

Edit: I solved the issue by getting the latest scikit-learn version and using the following:

```
gs.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, fit_params={'sample_weight': sw_train})
```

Comment: If you have the answer, please post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will lie around as unanswered.

Comment: I confirm the `fit_params` trick is the right answer. Please answer to yourself and validate your answer.

Comment: @ogrisel won't this cause `fit` to be called with the entire list of weights for each fold, rather than the weights of just the datapoints in the fold?

Comment: That's a good remark but this case is actually handled properly by the internal cross-validation routines: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L1093

Comment: @ogrisel Good find, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Just trying to close out this long hanging question...

You needed to get the last version of SKL and use the following:

```
gs.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, fit_params={'sample_weight': sw_train})
```

However, it is more in line with the documentation to pass `fit_params` to the constructor:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(C=1), [{'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [.1, 1, 10], 'probability': [True], 'sample_weight': sw_train}], fit_params={'sample_weight': sw_train})

gs.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

Comment: According to the docs `fit_params` should be passed to the constructor, not the `fit` method

Comment: What is the shape of `sw_train`? I tried `sw_train=[{1:1}]` and it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The previous answers are now obsolete. The dictionary `fit_params` should be passed to the `fit` method.

From the documentation for [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> **fit_params** : dict, optional
>
> Parameters to pass to the fit method.
>
> > Deprecated since version 0.19: fit_params as a constructor argument was deprecated in version 0.19 and will be removed in version 0.21. Pass fit parameters to the fit method instead.

Comment: Has anyone confirmed that this works correctly with `sample_weight`? `GridSearchCV` calls the estimator's `fit()` method repeatedly with different subsets of `Xtrain` and `ytrain`. Does it use the corresponding subset of the sample weights each time? I would guess that it doesn't; it just calls `fit(..., **fit_params)` each time. This works fine for params such as `verbose` that aren't tied to particular samples.

Comment: I've had a similar question about how `sample_weight` works in the past. You can see the question and answer here; I think this question is motivated by the same concern that you express here, but it's a little old. I don't know whether newer versions of `sklearn` work in a more intuitive way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581104/sklearn-gridsearchcv-not-using-sample-weight-in-score-function

Comment: Thanks. I did some more searching, and found https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2879, which shows that `GridSearchCV` is now programmed to pass the correct subset of `sample_weight` in each call to the estimator's `fit()` method. People are still dissatisfied because there's no simple way to use `sample_weight` for scoring in `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: Ah! Interesting. It's good to know that at least there's been some progress on that front. The solutions in the thread that I linked are functional but do leave something to be desired in terms of simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

In version 0.16.1, if you use `Pipeline`, you need to pass the param to `GridSearchCV` constructor:

```
clf = pipeline.Pipeline([('svm', svm_model)])
model = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = clf, param_grid=param_grid,
    fit_params={'svm__sample_weight': sw_train})
```

Comment: here is the discussion and I have noticed that this behavior is still there with the 0.17 http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/34191031/

Comment: What is the shape of `sw_train`? I tried `sw_train=[{1:1}]` and it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @AzizJaved the parameter can be found in the documentation for the particular [classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit). In this case, it is a one-dimensional array with one weight per sample (example).

Answer (score 4):

The following works in Sklearn 0.23.1,

```
grid_cv = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid,
                       scoring='recall', n_jobs=-1, cv=10)

grid_cv.fit(x_train_orig, y=y_train_orig,
            sample_weight=my_sample_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

OP's edit and other answers are not entirely correct. While for fitting `fit_params={'sample_weight': weights}` works, those weight **will not be used to compute validation loss!** ([github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2879)).

Consequently, cross-validation will report unweighted loss, and thus the hyper-parameter-tuning might get steered off into the wrong direction.

Here is my work-around for cross-validation with class weights using accuracy as metric. Should also work with other metrics.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.utils import compute_sample_weight
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer


def weighted_accuracy_eval(y_pred, y_true, **kwargs):
    balanced_class_weights_eval = compute_sample_weight(
        class_weight='balanced',
        y=y_true
    )
    out = accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred, y_true=y_true, sample_weight=balanced_class_weights_eval, **kwargs)
    return out


weighted_accuracy_eval_skl = make_scorer(weighted_accuracy_eval)

gridsearch = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=model,
    scoring=weighted_accuracy_eval,
    param_grid=paramGrid,
)

cv_result = gridsearch.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    fit_params=fit_params
)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further? What are the `fit_params` supposed to be in this case? Is it `{class_weight: weights_array}`? Does this fit and evaluate with a specified array of weights? It's not clear to me that's what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: As you can see this is a highly advanced and complicated example. OP already provides an answer along with other answers saying "use `fit_params`, so my answer here is really another spin on the situation. If I were to write a proper tutorial on fitting with weights and then to explain my workaround, it would become a medium article.

Comment: Nonetheless, `fit_params` is a dictionary of parameters that will be passed to the `.fit` method of your estimator. When using sklearn pipelines vs writing a custom loop you suddenly don't can't control deep behavior, e.g. the API does not provide a way to specify `class_weights` for imbalanced training. But you can work around using `fit_params`

Comment: So, `class_weights` in `fit_params` should comply with `estimator.fit(..., class_weights=weights_array)` -- for which see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972029/how-does-the-class-weight-parameter-in-scikit-learn-work

Answer (score 0):

Great question and great answers! (Thanks @Sycorax, @AN6U5, and @user1771485). All of them helped me a lot to find an answer to the specific case, where **I needed to use sample_weight during GridSearchCV, but my estimator was obtained using Pipeline**. The issue differs from the previous solutions because Pipeline does not support fit_param; indeed, if you try to use `fit_param = {... }` during the fit step (of GridSearchCV) you'll get

> Pipeline.fit does not accept the fit_param parameter. You can pass parameters to specific steps of your pipeline using the stepname__parameter format, e.g. `Pipeline.fit(X, y, logisticregression__sample_weight=sample_weight)`

The pipeline I was using was

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('normalizer', norm), ('estimator', svr)])
```

where `norm` was a normalization step, `svr = SVR()`, and the parameter grid

```
parameters_svr = dict (estimator = [svr], estimator__kernel =  ['rbf', 'sigmoid'], ...)
```

Then, as advised by @user1771485

```
grid = GridSearchCV (estimator = pipe, param_grid = parameters_svr, cv = 3,                            
                     scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', 
                     return_train_score = True, refit = True, n_jobs = -1)
```

and finally, (the part that truly matters)

```
grid.fit (X,y, estimator__sample_weight= weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

In scikit-learn version **1.1.1** you can pass `sample_weight` directly to the `fit()` of `GridSearchCV`.

For example:

```py
def get_weights(cls):
    class_weights = {
        # class-labels based on your dataset.
        0: 1,
        1: 4,
        2: 1,
    }

    return [class_weights[cl] for cl in cls]

grid = {
    "max_depth": [3, 4, 5, 6],
    "n_estimators": range(20, 70, 10),
    "learning_rate": np.arange(0.25, 0.50, 0.05),
}

xgb_clf = XGBClassifier(random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
xgb_cvm = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_clf, param_grid=grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
xgb_cvm.fit(X, y, sample_weight=get_weights(y))
```