# How class_weight emphasis a class in in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to know how scikit-learn put more emphasis on a class when we use the parameter `class_weight`. Is it an oversampling of the minority sampling ?

Answer (score 0):

Neither. I think that it instead affects the loss:

- higher loss for the class with higher weight.
- lower loss for the class with a lower weight.

The matter is discussed more in depth in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972029/how-does-the-class-weight-parameter-in-scikit-learn-work).

Comment: This is generally true. However, I think the question is how it is actually done?

Comment: Yes the question is more how it penalize the majority class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a single method of treating `class_weight` for all the algorithms.

The way Decision Trees (and Forests) deals with this is by modifying the weights of each sample according to its class.

You can consider weighting samples as a more general case of oversampling **all** the minority class samples (using weights you can "oversample" fractions of samples).