# sklearn GridSearchCV not using sample_weight in score function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have data with differing weights for each sample. In my application, it is important that these weights are accounted for in estimating the model and comparing alternative models.

I'm using `sklearn` to estimate models and to compare alternative hyperparameter choices. But this unit test shows that `GridSearchCV` does not apply `sample_weights` to estimate scores.

Is there a way to have `sklearn` use `sample_weight` to score the models?

Unit test:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RepeatedKFold


def grid_cv(X_in, y_in, w_in, cv, max_features_grid, use_weighting):
  out_results = dict()

  for k in max_features_grid:
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=256,
                                 criterion="entropy",
                                 warm_start=False,
                                 n_jobs=-1,
                                 random_state=RANDOM_STATE,
                                 max_features=k)
    for train_ndx, test_ndx in cv.split(X=X_in, y=y_in):
      X_train = X_in[train_ndx, :]
      y_train = y_in[train_ndx]
      w_train = w_in[train_ndx]
      y_test = y[test_ndx]

      clf.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, sample_weight=w_train)

      y_hat = clf.predict_proba(X=X_in[test_ndx, :])
      if use_weighting:
        w_test = w_in[test_ndx]
        w_i_sum = w_test.sum()
        score = w_i_sum / w_in.sum() * log_loss(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_hat, sample_weight=w_test)
      else:
        score = log_loss(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_hat)

      results = out_results.get(k, [])
      results.append(score)
      out_results.update({k: results})

  for k, v in out_results.items():
    if use_weighting:
      mean_score = sum(v)
    else:
      mean_score = np.mean(v)
    out_results.update({k: mean_score})

  best_score = min(out_results.values())
  best_param = min(out_results, key=out_results.get)
  return best_score, best_param


if __name__ == "__main__":
  RANDOM_STATE = 1337
  X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
  sample_weight = np.array([1 + 100 * (i % 25) for i in range(len(X))])
  # sample_weight = np.array([1 for _ in range(len(X))])

  inner_cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=1, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

  outer_cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=1, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

  rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=256,
                               criterion="entropy",
                               warm_start=False,
                               n_jobs=-1,
                               random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
  search_params = {"max_features": [1, 2, 3, 4]}


  fit_params = {"sample_weight": sample_weight}
  my_scorer = make_scorer(log_loss, 
               greater_is_better=False, 
               needs_proba=True, 
               needs_threshold=False)

  grid_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc,
                          scoring=my_scorer,
                          cv=inner_cv,
                          param_grid=search_params,
                          refit=True,
                          return_train_score=False,
                          iid=False)  # in this usage, the results are the same for `iid=True` and `iid=False`
  grid_clf.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  print("This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV: %.6f." % -grid_clf.best_score_)

  msg = """This is the best out-of-sample score %s weighting using grid_cv: %.6f."""
  score_with_weights, param_with_weights = grid_cv(X_in=X,
                                                   y_in=y,
                                                   w_in=sample_weight,
                                                   cv=inner_cv,
                                                   max_features_grid=search_params.get(
                                                     "max_features"),
                                                   use_weighting=True)
  print(msg % ("WITH", score_with_weights))

  score_without_weights, param_without_weights = grid_cv(X_in=X,
                                                         y_in=y,
                                                         w_in=sample_weight,
                                                         cv=inner_cv,
                                                         max_features_grid=search_params.get(
                                                           "max_features"),
                                                         use_weighting=False)
  print(msg % ("WITHOUT", score_without_weights))
```

Which produces output:

```
This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV: 0.135692.
This is the best out-of-sample score WITH weighting using grid_cv: 0.099367.
This is the best out-of-sample score WITHOUT weighting using grid_cv: 0.135692.
```

Explanation: Since manually computing the loss without weighting produces the same scoring as `GridSearchCV`, we know that the sample weights are not being used.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## sklearn version >= 1.4 and 1.4 nightly releases

From sklearn 1.4 (release date somewhere around October 2023), and nightly releases already available from September 2023 which you can install following guides from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#installing-nightly-builds), you can use the new [metadata routing mechanism](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/metadata_routing.html).

You can simply decide which objects should or should not receive metadata such as `sample_weight`, like the following script:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import set_config
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RepeatedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

set_config(enable_metadata_routing=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RANDOM_STATE = 1337
    X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
    sample_weight = np.array([1 + 100 * (i % 25) for i in range(len(X))])
    search_params = {"max_features": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
    cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=1, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

    rfc_weighted = RandomForestClassifier(
        n_estimators=256,
        criterion="entropy",
        warm_start=False,
        n_jobs=1,
        random_state=RANDOM_STATE,
    ).set_fit_request(sample_weight=True)

    rfc_unweighted = RandomForestClassifier(
        n_estimators=256,
        criterion="entropy",
        warm_start=False,
        n_jobs=1,
        random_state=RANDOM_STATE,
    ).set_fit_request(sample_weight=False)

    scorer_weighted = make_scorer(
        log_loss, greater_is_better=False, needs_proba=True, needs_threshold=False
    ).set_score_request(sample_weight=True)

    scorer_unweighted = make_scorer(
        log_loss, greater_is_better=False, needs_proba=True, needs_threshold=False
    ).set_score_request(sample_weight=False)

    for rfc, rfc_is_weighted in zip([rfc_weighted, rfc_unweighted], [True, False]):
        for scorer, scorer_is_weighted in zip(
            [scorer_weighted, scorer_unweighted], [True, False]
        ):
            grid_clf = GridSearchCV(
                estimator=rfc,
                scoring=scorer,
                cv=cv,
                param_grid=search_params,
                refit=True,
                return_train_score=False,
            )
            if rfc_is_weighted or scorer_is_weighted:
                grid_clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
            else:
                grid_clf.fit(X, y)
            print(
                "This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV with "
                f"(is scorer weighted: {scorer_is_weighted}), (is rfc weighted: "
                f"{rfc_is_weighted}): {-grid_clf.best_score_}"
            )
```

which will output:

```
This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV with (is scorer weighted: True), (is rfc weighted: True): 0.09180030568650309
This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV with (is scorer weighted: False), (is rfc weighted: True): 0.1225297422810374
This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV with (is scorer weighted: True), (is rfc weighted: False): 0.09064253271691491
This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV with (is scorer weighted: False), (is rfc weighted: False): 0.12187958644498716
```

## sklearn version < 1.4

The `GridSearchCV` takes a `scoring` as input, which can be callable. You can see the details of how to change the scoring function, and also how to pass your own scoring function [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring). Here's the relevant piece of code from that page for the sake of completeness:

[image]

**EDIT**: The *fit_params* is passed only to the fit functions, and not the score functions. If there are parameters which are supposed to be passed to the `scorer`, they should be passed to the `make_scorer`. But that still doesn't solve the issue here, since that would mean that the whole `sample_weight` parameter would be passed to `log_loss`, whereas only the part which corresponds to `y_test` at the time of calculating the loss should be passed.

`sklearn` does NOT support such a thing, but you can hack your way through, using a `padas.DataFrame`. The good news is, `sklearn` understands a `DataFrame`, and keeps it that way. Which means you can exploit the `index` of a `DataFrame` as you see in the code here:

```
  # more code

  X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
  index = ['r%d' % x for x in range(len(y))]
  y_frame = pd.DataFrame(y, index=index)
  sample_weight = np.array([1 + 100 * (i % 25) for i in range(len(X))])
  sample_weight_frame = pd.DataFrame(sample_weight, index=index)

  # more code

  def score_f(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight):
      return log_loss(y_true.values, y_pred,
                      sample_weight=sample_weight.loc[y_true.index.values].values.reshape(-1),
                      normalize=True)

  score_params = {"sample_weight": sample_weight_frame}
  my_scorer = make_scorer(score_f,
                          greater_is_better=False, 
                          needs_proba=True, 
                          needs_threshold=False,
                          **score_params)

  grid_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc,
                          scoring=my_scorer,
                          cv=inner_cv,
                          param_grid=search_params,
                          refit=True,
                          return_train_score=False,
                          iid=False)  # in this usage, the results are the same for `iid=True` and `iid=False`
  grid_clf.fit(X, y_frame)
  
  # more code
```

As you see, the `score_f` uses the `index` of `y_true` to find which parts of `sample_weight` to use. For the sake of completeness, here's the whole code:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RepeatedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import  make_scorer
import pandas as pd

def grid_cv(X_in, y_in, w_in, cv, max_features_grid, use_weighting):
  out_results = dict()

  for k in max_features_grid:
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=256,
                                 criterion="entropy",
                                 warm_start=False,
                                 n_jobs=1,
                                 random_state=RANDOM_STATE,
                                 max_features=k)
    for train_ndx, test_ndx in cv.split(X=X_in, y=y_in):
      X_train = X_in[train_ndx, :]
      y_train = y_in[train_ndx]
      w_train = w_in[train_ndx]
      y_test = y_in[test_ndx]

      clf.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, sample_weight=w_train)

      y_hat = clf.predict_proba(X=X_in[test_ndx, :])
      if use_weighting:
        w_test = w_in[test_ndx]
        w_i_sum = w_test.sum()
        score = w_i_sum / w_in.sum() * log_loss(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_hat, sample_weight=w_test)
      else:
        score = log_loss(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_hat)

      results = out_results.get(k, [])
      results.append(score)
      out_results.update({k: results})

  for k, v in out_results.items():
    if use_weighting:
      mean_score = sum(v)
    else:
      mean_score = np.mean(v)
    out_results.update({k: mean_score})

  best_score = min(out_results.values())
  best_param = min(out_results, key=out_results.get)
  return best_score, best_param


#if __name__ == "__main__":
if True:
  RANDOM_STATE = 1337
  X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
  index = ['r%d' % x for x in range(len(y))]
  y_frame = pd.DataFrame(y, index=index)
  sample_weight = np.array([1 + 100 * (i % 25) for i in range(len(X))])
  sample_weight_frame = pd.DataFrame(sample_weight, index=index)
  # sample_weight = np.array([1 for _ in range(len(X))])

  inner_cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=1, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

  outer_cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=1, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

  rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=256,
                               criterion="entropy",
                               warm_start=False,
                               n_jobs=1,
                               random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
  search_params = {"max_features": [1, 2, 3, 4]}


  def score_f(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight):
      return log_loss(y_true.values, y_pred,
                      sample_weight=sample_weight.loc[y_true.index.values].values.reshape(-1),
                      normalize=True)

  score_params = {"sample_weight": sample_weight_frame}
  my_scorer = make_scorer(score_f,
                          greater_is_better=False, 
                          needs_proba=True, 
                          needs_threshold=False,
                          **score_params)

  grid_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc,
                          scoring=my_scorer,
                          cv=inner_cv,
                          param_grid=search_params,
                          refit=True,
                          return_train_score=False,
                          iid=False)  # in this usage, the results are the same for `iid=True` and `iid=False`
  grid_clf.fit(X, y_frame)
  print("This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV: %.6f." % -grid_clf.best_score_)

  msg = """This is the best out-of-sample score %s weighting using grid_cv: %.6f."""
  score_with_weights, param_with_weights = grid_cv(X_in=X,
                                                   y_in=y,
                                                   w_in=sample_weight,
                                                   cv=inner_cv,
                                                   max_features_grid=search_params.get(
                                                     "max_features"),
                                                   use_weighting=True)
  print(msg % ("WITH", score_with_weights))

  score_without_weights, param_without_weights = grid_cv(X_in=X,
                                                         y_in=y,
                                                         w_in=sample_weight,
                                                         cv=inner_cv,
                                                         max_features_grid=search_params.get(
                                                           "max_features"),
                                                         use_weighting=False)
  print(msg % ("WITHOUT", score_without_weights))
```

The output of the code is then:

```
This is the best out-of-sample score using GridSearchCV: 0.095439.
This is the best out-of-sample score WITH weighting using grid_cv: 0.099367.
This is the best out-of-sample score WITHOUT weighting using grid_cv: 0.135692.
```

**EDIT 2**: as the comment bellow says:

> the difference in my score and the sklearn score using this solution
> originates in the way that I was computing a weighted average of
> scores. If you omit the weighted average portion of the code, the two
> outputs match to machine precision.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with `make_scorer`; this answer doesn't resolve the issue. I obtain the same results when using make_scorer to implement the `log_loss` (see updated code). Notably, the `log_loss` function itself takes `sample_weights` as an argument; however, since the output does not match the weighted score, we can infer that `fit` is not passing `sample_weights` to `my_scorer`. Stated another way, the problem isn't whether or not `make_scorer` is used, it's whether `GridSearchCV` is capable of passing sample weights to scoring functions.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer. One note -- the difference in my score and the `sklearn` score using this solution originates in the way that I was computing a weighted average of scores. If you omit the weighted average portion of the code, the two outputs match to machine precision.

Comment: Very good anwser and the only one, I could find on Stackoverflow.

Comment: No need to use a string index for y_frame and sample_weight_frame.  The default 0 to len(df)-1 index  worked fine for me.

Comment: I know, but I like to have indices strings so that they don't get confused or mistaken with the route numbers.

Comment: Useful. Too bad that sklearn does not support this :(

Comment: That's why we're working on it: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/22083 @hipoglucido

Comment: I've updated the code to use metadata routing.

Comment: @adrin, could you comment on the differences above with the metadata routing docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/metadata_routing.html#metadata-routing? Specifically, in those examples there's a `props` keyword passed to `cross_validate` whereas in these examples you never use a props keyword. Could props be passed to something like `GridSearchCV`, or how should we think about these differences?

Comment: @gammapoint I tried to use props in cross_validate and it threw an error. 
On this page they suggest using "params" instead 
https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v1.4.html

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I suppose that main metadata routing page is not current.

Comment: Sorry, the up to date link is https://scikit-learn.org/dev/metadata_routing.html I've updated the post with the correct link.

Comment: thanks for the correc link! @adrin could you have a look at my question here regarding the same topic? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77522941/using-sample-weights-through-metadata-routing-in-scikit-learn-in-nested-cross-va

Answer (score 3):

Currently in sklearn, `GridSearchCV`(and any classes inherit `BaseSearchCV`) only allow `sample_weight` in `**fit_params` but not using it in scoring, which is not correct, since CV pick the "best estimator" via unweighted score. Notes, when you `grid.fit(X, y, sample_weight=w)` only use sample weights in `fit`, not `score`.

There are two ways to solve this problems:

1. Handy method: add weight as the first columns in X. write your customized scoring function and transformer in your model.

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
# customized scorer
def weight_remover_scorer(estimator, X, y):
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    w = X[:,0]
    return your_scorer(y, y_pred, sample_weight=w)

# customized transformer
class WeightRemover(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return X[:,1:]

# in your main function
if __name__=='__main__':
    pipe = Pipeline([('remove_weight', WeightRemover()),('model',model)])
    params_grid = {'model__'+k:v for k,v in params_grid.items()}
    X = np.c_[train_w, X]
    X_test = np.c_[test_w, X_test]
    grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, params_grid, cv=5, scoring=weight_remover_scorer)
    grid.fit(X, y)
```

2. add features in `sklearn` class (wait for new upgrade). Just add parameters `sample_weight` in `BaseSearchCV` (default is `None`), safer indexing them in the same way as `fit_params = _check_fit_params(X, fit_params)`.

Comment: Oh, I forget to fit using sample weights in above code. Just to change `grid.fit(X, y)` to `grid.fit(X, y, sample_weight=w)` for the correct one!. Now we using sample_weight in both fit and score.

Comment: Oops... Still failed since `Pipeline` does not support `sample_weight` in `fit`. I also tried to add a class wrapper over it, which modify the fit function like `def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):
        w = X[:,0]
        self.nX = X.shape[1]-1
        return self.wrapped_estimator.fit(X[:,1:], y, sample_weight=w)`However, it's a local object and cannot pickle when trying to speed up by parallel....

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing out that there is an ongoing effort to support this important feature: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13432

But it seems that because of backward compatibility issues and the desire to tackle the more general problem of passing arbitrary sample related information it is taking a bit too long. The last attempt seems to be: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/16079

Here is a good review of the issue: http://deaktator.github.io/2019/03/10/the-error-in-the-comparator/